# memory space to implement 128-bit AES algorithm on 8 bit microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, algorithm

How to calculate(RAM and ROM) memory space needed to implement 128-bit AES algorithm on 8 bit microcontroller?

give some examples please...

Answer (score 0):

One way to calculate the space / ram required is to find a 128 bit AES library meant for embedded devices.

Because users of such libraries are faced with the same question than you are. The developers of the library usually provide this information in the documentation that comes with the library or directly on the web page.

The figures are usually dependent of the target platform and the exact compiler used. But this is usually accurate enough to know if that library could fit into your specific chip or not.

For a specific example, try to find that library into the application notes of the leader of the 8-bit market:

- Mirochip
- Atmel
- TI
- Renesas
- Etc